# Find the closest value to another value in a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to find the element in `yrs` that is closest to 2013 (`_tmp`).

```
yrs = [2000.0, 2001.0, 2002.0, 2003.0, 2004.0, 2005.0, 2006.0, 2007.0, 2008.0, 2009.0, 2010.0, 2011.0, 2012.0, 2014.0, 2015.0, 2016.0]
_tmp = 2013
min(yrs, key=lambda x: abs(x - _tmp))
```

I've tried with a list comprehension but it throws a `NameError`. How else can I do this? Perhaps with numpy?

Comment: working fine for me!

Comment: If you're using numpy (you tagged it so), then use `yrs[np.abs(np.array(yrs) - _tmp).argmin()]` which spits out 2012.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your interpreter? The code looks fine.

Comment: I am using python 3.6, are you on python 3.6 as well?

Comment: what is your numpy version?

Comment: Maybe python 3.6 doesn't like var names starting with an underscore? Try changing the name.

Comment: thanks @COLDSPEED, your soln works. I can accept it as a soln

Comment: I use python3.6 and it works fine. It shouldn't be a problem about python's version but about your code. You must did something wrong else.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ tried yours, still getting `2012.0`.

Comment: @user308827 Wrote one, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned, use `np.argmin`:

```
yrs[np.abs(np.array(yrs) - _tmp).argmin()]
```

---

- convert `yrs` to a `numpy.ndarray` (skip if already array)
- broadcasting subtraction of `_tmp` from every elements in `yrs`
- `np.abs` finds the absolute value (we want absolute least)
- `np.argmin` finds the index of the smallest value
- index into `yrs` to finish the job.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to find the closest value to a number

```
yrs = [2000.0, 2001.0, 2002.0, 2003.0, 2004.0, 2005.0, 2006.0, 2007.0, 2008.0, 2009.0, 2010.0, 2011.0, 2012.0, 2014.0, 2015.0, 2016.0]
yr = 2013

# creates a list l, with the difference between input year and items in yrs
# find the element having the minimum difference with the input element (yr)
l = [abs(x-yr) for x in yrs]
if l:
    print(int(yrs[l.index(min(l))]))

>>> 2012
```